# Issue with CQ5 versioning

Tags: java, spring, aem

I have got a strange problem with Adobe CQ5 versioning.
I'm doing two different operations(one is adding and the other updates) using the same user login.

```
28.07.2017 06:30:52.846 *ERROR* [Response--12] [publishing.create.commentary.PSI43457815.int-emp] com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.service.PublicationServiceImpl Update publication failed com.ubs.f35.content.sdk.data.DaoException: com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMException: Unable to create version.
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.dao.publication.PublicationDaoImpl.updatePublication(PublicationDaoImpl.java:208)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.dao.publication.PublicationDaoImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b8ac430f.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.common.aop.StopwatchMethodInterceptor.invoke(StopwatchMethodInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.sdk.session.SessionRequiredInterceptor.executeMethod(SessionRequiredInterceptor.java:106)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.sdk.session.SessionRequiredInterceptor.invoke(SessionRequiredInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.dao.publication.PublicationDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d66ec20a.updatePublication(<generated>)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.service.PublicationServiceImpl.unpermissionedUpdatePublicationInternal(PublicationServiceImpl.java:345)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.service.PublicationServiceImpl.updatePublicationInternal(PublicationServiceImpl.java:322)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.service.PublicationServiceImpl.updateSalesCommentary(PublicationServiceImpl.java:226)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.service.PublicationServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$7c3b2aad.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.common.aop.StopwatchMethodInterceptor.invoke(StopwatchMethodInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.sdk.session.SessionRequiredInterceptor.executeMethod(SessionRequiredInterceptor.java:106)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.sdk.session.SessionRequiredInterceptor.invoke(SessionRequiredInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.service.PublicationServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$449170e6.updateSalesCommentary(<generated>)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.messaging.publication.PublishPublicationMessageProcessor.updatePublication(PublishPublicationMessageProcessor.java:92)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.messaging.publication.PublishPublicationMessageProcessor.handleObject(PublishPublicationMessageProcessor.java:44)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.messaging.AbstractMessageProcessor.invoke(AbstractMessageProcessor.java:61)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.messaging.AbstractMessageProcessor$$FastClassByCGLIB$$6f62e747.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:617)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.messaging.publication.PublishPublicationMessageProcessor$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c3ef3346.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.ubs.f35.common.transport.events.lbm.ReceiveReplyCallbackHandler.processMessage(ReceiveReplyCallbackHandler.java:119)
    at com.ubs.f35.common.transport.events.threadpool.ThreadPoolReceiveReplyCallbackHandler.access$001(ThreadPoolReceiveReplyCallbackHandler.java:11)
    at com.ubs.f35.common.transport.events.threadpool.ThreadPoolReceiveReplyCallbackHandler$1.run(ThreadPoolReceiveReplyCallbackHandler.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.PageManagerImpl.createRevision(PageManagerImpl.java:1027)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.dao.publication.PublicationTemplate.createRevision(PublicationTemplate.java:410)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.dao.publication.PublicationDaoImpl.updatePublication(PublicationDaoImpl.java:205)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.StaleItemStateException: 124a7e07-1345-4bf7-81d2-c3c625ed62bc/{http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}isCheckedOut has been modified externally
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.version.VersionManagerImplBase.checkoutCheckin(VersionManagerImplBase.java:218)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.VersionManagerImpl.access$300(VersionManagerImpl.java:73)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.VersionManagerImpl$2.perform(VersionManagerImpl.java:142)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.VersionManagerImpl$2.perform(VersionManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:200)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.VersionManagerImpl.perform(VersionManagerImpl.java:96)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.VersionManagerImpl.checkout(VersionManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.checkout(NodeImpl.java:2875)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.PageManagerImpl.createRevision(PageManagerImpl.java:1094)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.StaleItemStateException: 124a7e07-1345-4bf7-81d2-c3c625ed62bc/{http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}isCheckedOut has been modified externally
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager$Update.begin(SharedItemStateManager.java:670)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.beginUpdate(SharedItemStateManager.java:1473)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.update(SharedItemStateManager.java:1503)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.LocalItemStateManager.update(LocalItemStateManager.java:398)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.XAItemStateManager.update(XAItemStateManager.java:354)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.LocalItemStateManager.update(LocalItemStateManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.version.VersionManagerImplBase$WriteOperation.save(VersionManagerImplBase.java:469)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.version.VersionManagerImplBase.checkoutCheckin(VersionManagerImplBase.java:215)
    ... 49 more
28.07.2017 06:30:52.846 *DEBUG* [Response--12] [STOPWATCH] com.ubs.f35.content.cms.common.aop.StopwatchMethodInterceptor PublicationServiceImpl.updateSalesCommentary=14m 27s
28.07.2017 06:30:52.847 *DEBUG* [Response--12] [null] com.ubs.f35.content.sdk.session.SessionRequiredInterceptor Ending transaction
28.07.2017 06:30:52.847 *ERROR* [Response--12] [null] com.ubs.f35.content.messaging.AbstractMessageProcessor 612ed2de-e27b-4f21-9039-46c40435a469 Invoke failed with code: SERVICE_ERROR com.ubs.f35.content.messaging.service.ServiceException: Update publication failed
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.service.PublicationServiceImpl.unpermissionedUpdatePublicationInternal(PublicationServiceImpl.java:353)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.service.PublicationServiceImpl.updatePublicationInternal(PublicationServiceImpl.java:322)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.service.PublicationServiceImpl.updateSalesCommentary(PublicationServiceImpl.java:226)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.service.PublicationServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$7c3b2aad.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.common.aop.StopwatchMethodInterceptor.invoke(StopwatchMethodInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.sdk.session.SessionRequiredInterceptor.executeMethod(SessionRequiredInterceptor.java:106)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.sdk.session.SessionRequiredInterceptor.invoke(SessionRequiredInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.service.PublicationServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$449170e6.updateSalesCommentary(<generated>)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.messaging.publication.PublishPublicationMessageProcessor.updatePublication(PublishPublicationMessageProcessor.java:92)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.messaging.publication.PublishPublicationMessageProcessor.handleObject(PublishPublicationMessageProcessor.java:44)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.messaging.AbstractMessageProcessor.invoke(AbstractMessageProcessor.java:61)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.messaging.AbstractMessageProcessor$$FastClassByCGLIB$$6f62e747.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:617)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.messaging.publication.PublishPublicationMessageProcessor$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c3ef3346.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.ubs.f35.common.transport.events.lbm.ReceiveReplyCallbackHandler.processMessage(ReceiveReplyCallbackHandler.java:119)
    at com.ubs.f35.common.transport.events.threadpool.ThreadPoolReceiveReplyCallbackHandler.access$001(ThreadPoolReceiveReplyCallbackHandler.java:11)
    at com.ubs.f35.common.transport.events.threadpool.ThreadPoolReceiveReplyCallbackHandler$1.run(ThreadPoolReceiveReplyCallbackHandler.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ubs.f35.content.sdk.data.DaoException: com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMException: Unable to create version.
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.dao.publication.PublicationDaoImpl.updatePublication(PublicationDaoImpl.java:208)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.dao.publication.PublicationDaoImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b8ac430f.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.common.aop.StopwatchMethodInterceptor.invoke(StopwatchMethodInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.sdk.session.SessionRequiredInterceptor.executeMethod(SessionRequiredInterceptor.java:106)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.sdk.session.SessionRequiredInterceptor.invoke(SessionRequiredInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.dao.publication.PublicationDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d66ec20a.updatePublication(<generated>)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.service.PublicationServiceImpl.unpermissionedUpdatePublicationInternal(PublicationServiceImpl.java:345)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMException: Unable to create version.
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.PageManagerImpl.createRevision(PageManagerImpl.java:1145)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.PageManagerImpl.createRevision(PageManagerImpl.java:1027)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.dao.publication.PublicationTemplate.createRevision(PublicationTemplate.java:410)
    at com.ubs.f35.content.cms.publishing.internal.dao.publication.PublicationDaoImpl.updatePublication(PublicationDaoImpl.java:205)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.StaleItemStateException: 124a7e07-1345-4bf7-81d2-c3c625ed62bc/{http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}isCheckedOut has been modified externally
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.version.VersionManagerImplBase.checkoutCheckin(VersionManagerImplBase.java:218)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.VersionManagerImpl.access$300(VersionManagerImpl.java:73)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.VersionManagerImpl$2.perform(VersionManagerImpl.java:142)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.VersionManagerImpl$2.perform(VersionManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:200)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.VersionManagerImpl.perform(VersionManagerImpl.java:96)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.VersionManagerImpl.checkout(VersionManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.checkout(NodeImpl.java:2875)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.PageManagerImpl.createRevision(PageManagerImpl.java:1094)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.StaleItemStateException: 124a7e07-1345-4bf7-81d2-c3c625ed62bc/{http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}isCheckedOut has been modified externally
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager$Update.begin(SharedItemStateManager.java:670)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.beginUpdate(SharedItemStateManager.java:1473)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.update(SharedItemStateManager.java:1503)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.LocalItemStateManager.update(LocalItemStateManager.java:398)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.XAItemStateManager.update(XAItemStateManager.java:354)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.LocalItemStateManager.update(LocalItemStateManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.version.VersionManagerImplBase$WriteOperation.save(VersionManagerImplBase.java:469)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.version.VersionManagerImplBase.checkoutCheckin(VersionManagerImplBase.java:215)
    ... 49 more
```

I believe that concurrent access might be the issue as the user is trying to update before the add operation even succeeds(we have got a pipeline that does the job of saving under the hood,but to the user, we show that the add operation is successful beforehand). We've also implemented thread locking mechanism so that only one operation(add/update) can be allowed at a time.
As a workaround, we've also tried to refresh the JCR session for the user using session.refresh method so that the state of the item can be updated before saving.

But nothing seems to be working.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: which version of AEM/crx?

Comment: It's CQ5 and the crx version is 2.2.0.85